# When android actually renders and displays the activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to understand on which stage android OS is rendering layouts, in order to be able to access views in my ListView. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layouts are created in `onCreate()`:

> The entire lifetime of an activity happens between the first call to
>   onCreate(Bundle) through to a single final call to onDestroy().

[image]

The Activity is visible from `onStart()`:

> The visible lifetime of an activity happens between a call to
>   onStart() until a corresponding call to onStop(). During this time the
>   user can see the activity on-screen

Source: the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).